# Calling a PLSQL subprogram from within SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

From within an Oracle stored procedure, is it possible to call a subprogram from within a SQL statement? Perhaps an example would be a better way to explain it. Here is a straightforward example:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE p_test(in_text VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(in_text);
  END;
BEGIN
  SELECT p_test('Test') FROM dual;
END;
/
```

However, this results in an ORA-00904 error. So, I'm not confidant the answer to my question will be yes. Nevertheless, I still wanted to ask.

What my real program is trying to do is compare over a hundred pairs of fields. So, something like this:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE p_compare
  (in_old VARCHAR2, in_new VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    IF in_old <> in_new THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Mismatch');

      INSERT INTO tbl_mismatch VALUES (in_old, in_new);
    END IF;
  END;

v_old_value_a VARCHAR2(30);
v_new_value_a VARCHAR2(30);
v_old_value_b VARCHAR2(30);
v_new_value_b VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN
--What I would like to do
SELECT p_compare(old_value_a, new_value_a), p_compare(old_value_b, new_value_b)
FROM (SELECT 'ALPHA' old_value_a, 'ALPHA' new_value_a, 'BETA' old_value_b, 'DELTA' new_value_b FROM dual);

--What I am currently doing
--I have over 100 pairs of fields that I am comparing 
--Declaring two variables for each pair becomes cumbersome
SELECT old_value_a, new_value_a, old_value_b, new_value_b
INTO v_old_value_a, v_new_value_a, v_old_value_b, v_new_value_b
FROM (SELECT 'ALPHA' old_value_a, 'ALPHA' new_value_a, 'BETA' old_value_b, 'DELTA' new_value_b FROM dual);

p_compare(v_old_value_a, v_new_value_a);
p_compare(v_old_value_b, v_new_value_b);
END;
/
```

So, if perhaps what I am trying is not possible, is there a better way to accomplish my end-goal?

Comment: You can call a function that way, not a procedure.What do you expect from `SELECT p_test('Test') FROM dual`?

Comment: Aleksej, for the purposes of the example, I would expect `SELECT p_test('Test') FROM dual` to return the same thing as `p_test('Test')`. In the actual code, the subprogram is doing the comparison and a few additional operations and inserting the differing values into a table.

Comment: If p_test is a procedure, it does not return anything at all; if you need to get some result, you need to create a function that returns a value

Comment: You can't call a procedure from SQL because procedures don't return a value, and if you think about it the only places where you'd call a subprogram from an SQL statement are places where a value is required. Thus, you can call FUNCTIONS from SQL statements but not PROCEDURES. Best of luck.

Comment: I am not trying to return a value. I am passing two values to the subprogram, and if they are different, the subprogram should insert into a table.

Comment: So why do you need a query? Define a procedure and call it, without using a select

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call a procedure this way:

```
  SQL> DECLARE
  2      PROCEDURE p_compare(in_old VARCHAR2, in_new VARCHAR2) IS
  3      BEGIN
  4          IF in_old <> in_new
  5          THEN
  6              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Mismatch');
  7
  8              INSERT INTO tbl_mismatch
  9                   VALUES (in_old, in_new);
 10          END IF;
 11      END;
 12  BEGIN
 13      p_compare('AA', 'BB');
 14      p_compare('XX', 'XX');
 15  END;
 16  /
Mismatch

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tbl_mismatch;

IN_OLD                         IN_NEW
------------------------------ ------------------------------
AA                             BB
```

If you would use a function to call inside an SQL statement, this is a way:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_compare(in_old VARCHAR2, in_new VARCHAR2)
  2      RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  3  BEGIN
  4      IF in_old <> in_new
  5      THEN
  6          RETURN 'Mismatch';
  7      ELSE
  8          RETURN 'Match';
  9      END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      v_compare_result1                       VARCHAR2(30);
  3      v_compare_result2                       VARCHAR2(30);
  4  BEGIN
  5      SELECT f_compare(old_value_a, new_value_a), f_compare(old_value_b, new_value_b)
  6        INTO v_compare_result1, v_compare_result2
  7        FROM (SELECT 'ALPHA' old_value_a,
  8                     'ALPHA' new_value_a,
  9                     'BETA' old_value_b,
 10                     'DELTA' new_value_b
 11                FROM DUAL);
 12
 13      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Compare 1: ' || v_compare_result1);
 14      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Compare 2: ' || v_compare_result2);
 15  END;
 16  /
Compare 1: Match
Compare 2: Mismatch

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: But I am pulling the values that need to be compared from a table. I'd prefer not to have to declare two variables for each field to be compared. In my example, I have v_old_value_a/b. Well, imagine v_[old/new]_value_[01-99].

Comment: Perhaps the function is the best way to go. Looks like I'd need only one variable per comparison as opposed to two.

Comment: Guess function doesn't work when it is embedded within the procedure, as I was hoping with the subprogram. I am working with a vendor app so I am a bit limited.

Comment: In SQL you can only call a stored function, not one defined in your block

Comment: Also the function can be in the same PL/SQL package as long as it's public (i.e. declared in the package header). Alternatively if there aren't too many rows to process you could loop through them and use the local function within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use variables you have to declare them before you declare any inline function/procedure.

This one works:

```
DECLARE

    x NUMBER;

    PROCEDURE p_test(in_text VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(in_text);
    END;

    FUNCTION give_me_five RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 5;
    END;

BEGIN
    x := give_me_five;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( x );

    p_test('Hello World');
END;
```

but this one does not work:

```
DECLARE

    FUNCTION give_me_five RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 5;
    END;

    x NUMBER;

BEGIN
    x := give_me_five;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( x );
END;

ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "X" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure
ORA-06550: line 13, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
   member constructor map
```